# How can I use Augeas to manage the `!includedir` directive for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, augeas

I have a MySQL configuration file with an `!includedir` directive. The directive seems to show up properly when the lens examines the file:

```
$ sudo augtool print /files/etc/my.cnf | fgrep includedir
/files/etc/my.cnf/!includedir = "/etc/mysql/conf.d/"
```

However, while augtool prints out the path when examining */etc/my.cnf*, it keeps complaining about an invalid path expression if I try to print or examine the actual node. For example:

```
$ sudo augtool
augtool> print /files/etc/my.cnf/!includedir
error: Invalid path expression
error: empty name
/files/etc/my.cnf/|=|!includedir
```

How can I use Augeas 1.0.0 to manage the `!includedir` directive in the */etc/my.cnf* file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!` cannot be used in paths. You can however use the `label()` function to select that node:

```
augtool> print /files/etc/mysql/my.cnf/*[label()="!includedir"]
/files/etc/mysql/my.cnf/!includedir = "/etc/mysql/conf.d/"
```

[Path expressions](https://github.com/hercules-team/augeas/wiki/Path-expressions) are documented on the Augeas wiki.

Comment: There appears no reason that ! cannot be in a path, at least none that I can see in the documentation you linked to

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem, mysql uses .ini like config files, and every tool tries to handle it like that.. I don't found normal solution for that, but you can always fork / rewrite the current .ini parsing method. 
And that's not a really good thing.

At the end I solved this by my site like you can have 2 my.cnf files simultaneously /etc/my.cnf and ~/.my.cnf I tried to move my client bindings to these two files. (ok, when they are server config options, I don't have any idea what to do, expect hackety-hack.) :(